# Сравнение пробела типа string

Tags: c#, строки, char

Каким образом в C# можно сравнить символ строки, обращаясь по индексу в цикле с пробелом? Как я понял, обращение по индексу к строке - возвращает тип `char`, потому что компилятор ругается что нельзя сравнивать тип `char` и `string`.

Но, я не понимаю почему обращение к строке по индексу возвращает тип `char`. Как тогда сравнивать подобное в C#?

```
 public static string RemoveStartSpaces(string text)
{
    int i = 0;
    while (text[i] == " "){
        Console.WriteLine(text[i]);
        i++;
    }
}
```

> Operator '==' cannot be applied to operands of type 'char' and
>   'string'

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Все верно говорит компилятор. Для `char` нужно использовать одинарные кавычки

```
public static string RemoveStartSpaces(string text)
{
    int i = 0;
    while (text[i] == ' '){
        Console.WriteLine(text[i]);
        i++;
    }
}
```

в данном случае, ты берешь лишь символ строки, а именно `i-тый` символ, а символ имеет тип `char`